# How to set reminder for incoming or outgoing meeting requests

Tags: vba, outlook

When I create/update meeting requests OR receive a meeting request (skype/team meeting or regular meeting), I want to check if a reminder has been set. If not, set a reminder for 15 minutes before the meeting.

Some searching brought me code I included in the "ThisOutlookSession" module. No reminders are added.

```
Public WithEvents objCalendar As Outlook.Folder
Public WithEvents objCalendarItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set objCalendar = Outlook.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
    Set objCalendarItems = objCalendar.Items
End Sub

Private Sub objCalendarItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    Call SetReminder(Item)
End Sub

Private Sub objCalendarItems_ItemChange(ByVal Item As Object)
    Call SetReminder(Item)
End Sub

Private Sub SetReminder(ByVal objCalendarItem As Object)
    If TypeOf Item Is MeetingItem Then
        Set objMeetingRequest = Item
        Set objMeeting = objMeetingRequest.GetAssociatedAppointment(True)
        'Check if reminder existing
        If objMeeting.ReminderSet = False Then
            objMeeting.ReminderSet = True
            objMeeting.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 15
            objMeeting.Save
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Apologies if this is too simple, but did you restart Outlook? The Application_Startup code won't execute until you restart Outlook.

Comment: Also, does your code do something different than File - Options - Calendar - Calendar Options - Default reminders?

Comment: @DickKusleika - Yes, I had restarted outlook after updating the code. I am actually trying to monitor each incoming and outgoing meeting requests and trying to ensure that there is a 15 min reminder in all of them. Not exactly sure if the code is doing something else :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there is no `Item` object passed to the `SetReminder` method.

You need to check for `AppointmentItem` instead of `MeetingItem` in the code.

```
Private Sub SetReminder(ByVal objCalendarItem As Object)
    Dim objMeeting as AppointmentItem     
If TypeOf objCalendarItem Is AppointmentItem Then
       Set objMeeting = objCalendarItem 
        'Check if reminder existing
          If objMeeting.ReminderSet = False Then
             objMeeting.ReminderSet = True
             objMeeting.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 15
             objMeeting.Save
          End If
    End If
End Sub
```

If required you may check out the [MeetingStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.meetingstatus) property.